# Test caching with Mocha and Supertest

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have an express app that implements some caching/memoization in a few endpoints (the calls can take several seconds to run, so I save results for various amounts of time depending on the nature of the endpoint). When I'm running the unit tests via Mocha using Supertest, however, each call is taking the longer period of time. How can I actually test that the caching portion of my application is functioning properly?

When I run the node server by itself, I can see the time for each return (e.g. 3979.848 ms for the first, 3.180 ms for the second), and *it* is working as intended, but the *tests* aren't behaving the same way.

What do I need to do to test the caching/memoization? Can it be done with these tools? Do I need to utilize some other module?

My code looks like this:

```
var supertest = require('supertest');
var base_url = 'http://localhost:3000';
var server = supertest(base_url);

describe('big section', function() {
    describe('test section', function() {
        it('should do a thing', function(done) {
            this.timeout(10000);
            server
                .get('/url1')
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    //stuff
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
    describe('test section', function() {
        it('should do a similar thing, but faster', function(done) {
            this.timeout(10000); //I should be able to reduce this a lot
            server
                .get('/url1')
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    //stuff
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```